# Correct syntax for **params argument to API call

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I am trying to use the python-binance wrapper to the Binance API to write a simple little trading bot, mostly for the sake of learning how. I am currently stuck trying to get the price of a particular trading pair using the `client.get_symbol_ticker()` function, which can be found [here](https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/blob/master/binance/client.py) on line 827.

The string I need to send in is of the form `"AAABBB"` where AAA is the first ticker symbol and BBB is the symbol in which I want the price of AAA. However, I am not getting the syntax right. When I pass in a string:

```
client.get_symbol_ticker('ETHBTC')
```

I get `TypeError: get_symbol_ticker() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

if I do

```
client.get_symbol_ticker(params = 'ETHBTC')
```

I get `BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-1104): Not all sent parameters were read; read '0' parameter(s) but was sent '1'.`

Clearly I am just getting the syntax for the call wrong. The function prototype looks like this:

```
 def get_symbol_ticker(self, **params):
    """Latest price for a symbol or symbols.
    https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#24hr-ticker-price-change-statistics
    :param symbol:
    :type symbol: str
```

Can someone tell me the proper syntax to use when calling this function?

Comment: Your two snippets are the same.

Comment: Woops, ctrl+C mistake. One moment. EDIT: fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call should be `client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol = 'ETHBTC')`. The only way to know this is to look at the docstrings:

```
:param symbol:
:type symbol: str
```

This tells you it expects a keyword parameter named `symbol`.

`**params` means "take all keyword arguments and return them as a dictionary in the variable `params`". So in the case of the method call I provided above, `params` would be:

```
{'symbol': 'ETHBTC'}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am new to this, I did not really know how to read the doscstring. I'll know for next time. \